# "Брелок", "брелоки"

Tags: лингвистика

Почему, если единственное число "брелок", то множественное - "брелоки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно говорить "брелоки" (также, как, например, "валет - валеты"). Это слово заимствованное и гласная тут не выпадает. Часто употребляемый вариант "брелки" является неграмотным.

Comment: Спасибо, этого я не знал.

Answer (score 2):

Предпочтительно: *брелоки*, но допустимо и *брелки*. Раньше склонение слова *брелок* с выпадением гласного (*брелка, брелку*) рассматривалось как ошибочное, поскольку слово это заимствованное и, в отличие от русских слов с беглым О (*замок – замка, кружок – кружка, совок – совка* и т. п.), в слове *брелок* выпадения гласного О происходить не должно; единственно верными считались формы *брелока, брелоку*. Однако многие словари последних лет признают формы *брелка, брелку* допустимыми, т. е. этот вариант постепенно завоевывает право на существование. Со временем он имеет все шансы стать основным, поскольку для носителя языка грамматическая разница между *брелок* и такими словами, как *замок, щенок, дружок, венок* и т. п. неочевидна.